# ant exec task variable length arg

Tags: ant

I have a command that accepts variable lenght of arguments that I need to execute.  I fortuantely for me the arguments to ant that I need to pass to the command  are of the form  "-Dkey=value"

ant bootstrap -Dkey1=value1 -Dkey2=value2 -Dkey3=value3 ....

-Dkey3=value3 may or may not be present.  If key3 has been defined I need to passed to the execute task for cmd as in

```
cmd -Dkey1=value1 -Dkey2=value2 -Dkey3=value3
```

else 
    cmd -Dkey1=value1 -Dkey2=value2

I am hoping there is a more reasonable way of doing something like

```
<target name="bootstrap">
   <exec executable="cmd">
       <arg value="-Dkey1=${key1}"/>
       <arg value="-Dkey2=${key2}"/>
       <arg value="-Dkey3=${key3}">
           <condition>
                <isset property="key3"/>
           </condition>
       </arg>
       ....
    </exec>
```

but arg does not like condition.

I have also thought about

```
<target name=bootstrap depends="with_key3, without_key3/>
<target name="with_key3" if="key3">
    <exec executable="cmd">
       <arg value="-Dkey1=${key1}"/>
       <arg value="-Dkey2=${key2}"/>
       <arg value="-Dkey3=${key3}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
<target name="without_key3" if="?????"
      <exec executable="cmd">
       <arg value="-Dkey1=${key1}"/>
       <arg value="-Dkey2=${key2}"/>
    </exec>
</target
```

how to I test if property is not preset?
any better solutions

Comment: found my answer for target without_key3 use "unless" instead of if

Comment: please post this as the answer (as soon as you are able too, depending on your rep and priviliges)